# Export into a same file items from two different spiders using CrawlerProcess

Tags: python, scrapy

***UPDATED***

I am using the following example code following the [Scrapy documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script).

```
# main_test.py

import time
from typing import Any

import pandas
from scrapy import Field, Item
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy.http import Request, Response
from scrapy.spiders import Spider


class EmptyTagsFieldPipeline:
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if item["tags"] is None:
            raise DropItem("Empty tags field.")

        return item

class WrongTypeTextFieldPipeline:
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        try:
            str(item["text"])

            return item
        except ValueError:
            raise DropItem("Wrong type text field.")


def author_serializer(author):
    return f"Author: {author}"


class GenericItem(Item):
    text = Field(serializer=str)
    author = Field(serializer=author_serializer)
    tags = Field()


class ToScrapeSpiderXPath(Spider):
    name = 'toscrape-xpath'
    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response: Response, **kwargs: Any) -> Any:
        for quote in response.xpath('//div[@class="quote"]'):
            item = GenericItem()

            item['text'] = quote.xpath('./span[@class="text"]/text()').extract_first()
            item['author'] = quote.xpath('.//small[@class="author"]/text()').extract_first()
            item['tags'] = quote.xpath('.//div[@class="tags"]/a[@class="tag"]/text()').extract()

            yield item

        next_page_url = response.xpath('//li[@class="next"]/a/@href').extract_first()
        if next_page_url is not None:
            yield Request(response.urljoin(next_page_url))


def build_export(export_filename: str):
    process = CrawlerProcess(
        settings={
            "FEEDS": {
                export_filename: {
                    "format": "json",
                },
            },
            "ITEM_PIPELINES": {
                "main_test.EmptyTagsFieldPipeline": 300,
                "main_test.WrongTypeTextFieldPipeline": 301,
            },
            "LOG_LEVEL": "INFO",
            "REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION": "2.7",
            "DOWNLOAD_DELAY": 1,
            "ROBOTSTXT_OBEY": False,
        }
    )

    process.crawl(ToScrapeSpiderXPath)
    process.crawl(ToScrapeSpiderXPath)

    process.start()  # the script will block here until the crawling is finished


def main():
    export_filename = f"data/{time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')}_toscrape_export.json"
    build_export(export_filename)
    export = pandas.read_json(export_filename)

    print(export)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It is producing one json file as expected, but with multiple list inside (multiple opening and closing brackets), which raise an error when reading with Pandas.

The issue when I choose csv instead of json is different. In that scenario, headers can be found twice within the export file : at the beginning as expected and at the middle of the file, among items.

Is there any way to produce one clean file at the end?

Comment: without knowing the implementation of your spider it's kinda hard to help. please provide a minimal reproducible example

Comment: I just updated my question with a real "working" example to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful! Ideally, leave the rest of the question intact as well, so you don't change the scope (for example dropping the empty JSON bit), but the example is much appreciated.

Comment: I've amended my answer accordingly

Comment: If one of the answers helped, you might want to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Your main issue is the fact that you are outputting to the same json file asynchronously causing `class scrapy.exporters.JsonItemExporter` to output 2 complete json objects on top of each other in 1 file, therefore breaking the json format like so:

```
{"text": "", "author": "", "tags": []}
]{"text": "", "author": "", "tags": []},
```

However, if you insist on having multiple instances running you may have to reconsider your approach, you have few options going forward:

- Separate your spider instances [Running multiple spiders in
  the same process](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html?highlight=multiple%20scraper#running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process).
- Build your own post processing workflow [Post-Processing](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#post-processing).
- And last but not least, the easiest solution would be to change the
  way you save your data ie using json lines, Pickle or Marshall.

Here is an example using json lines to achieve a better result with minimal changes **(FYI, this does not handle duplicates as I am assuming you won't be running your scrappers on the same data concurrently)**:

```
def build_export(export_filename: str):
    process = CrawlerProcess(
        settings={
            "FEEDS": {
                export_filename: {
                    "format": "jsonl", #change format to jsonl/jsonline instead of json
                },
            },
            "ITEM_PIPELINES": {
                "main_test.EmptyTagsFieldPipeline": 300,
                "main_test.WrongTypeTextFieldPipeline": 301,
            },
            "LOG_LEVEL": "INFO",
            "REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION": "2.7",
            "DOWNLOAD_DELAY": 1,
            "ROBOTSTXT_OBEY": False,
        }
    )

process.crawl(ToScrapeSpiderXPath)
process.crawl(ToScrapeSpiderXPath)

process.start()
```

.

```
def main():
    export_filename = f"data/{time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')}_toscrape_export.jsonl" #jsonl file format instead of json 
    build_export(export_filename)
    
    #Extract lines of json and make it into its own object
    with open(export_filename) as f:
        data = [json.loads(line) for line in f]
    
    #Export the json object to pandas dataframe
    export = pandas.json_normalize(data)

    print(export)
```

Output result:
[image]

Comment: Using jsonl instead is a much nicer solution! kudos

Answer (score 1):

Both spiders are writing the items they're reading into the provided file. Therefore, it will contain duplicates (the headings as a minimum if they're equal).

To deal with this "properly" you'll want to use a [duplicates filter](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#duplicates-filter), but I found that it doesn't play nice with multiple spiders. I think this is due to every spider using their own pipeline, but I can't tell you for sure.

Using your provided example spiders, the easiest way to do this is to write everything to a CSV file, read that, do post-processing and dump it to JSON afterwards. This is basically what a duplicate filter would do as well.

I've changed your main method to give you an idea of what you could do.

```py
def main():
    export_basename = f"data/{time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')}_toscrape_export"
    export_tmpname = export_basename + ".csv"
    export_filename = export_basename + ".json"

    build_export(export_tmpname)
    with open(export_tmpname) as tmp_export:
        reader = csv.reader(tmp_export)
        rows = [row for row in reader]
        header = rows[0]
        rest = rows[1:]
        # you probably want additional logic here
        filtered_rows = [header, *[row for row in rest if row != header]]

    with open(export_filename, "w") as export_file:
        json.dump(filtered_rows, export_file)
    export = pandas.read_json(export_filename)

    print(export)
```

Of course, you could move this code into `build_export` as well, and you will have to change the settings in `build_export` accordingly, so it outputs CSV.

```
"FEEDS": {
    export_filename: {
        "format": "csv",
    },
},
```

Another way would be to use multiple processes, dump into temporary files, and join the results manually afterwards. But I think that would be a lot of hassle and might cost performance because you force things to be sequential.

Comment: If I understand correctly, exporters are at the spider level and not at the "bot"/"process" level ? Meaning that each spider export items to the configured file and format - in settings - and with it append each time headers (for csv) of brackets (for json).

Comment: @Benjamin that's my understanding as well